# Google Sheet conditional format if a cell contains the same text in a row from another tab

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I am trying to setup conditional format.

I found the following code:

```
=AND(A2:A=indirect("Blad2!A2:A");A2:A<>"")
```

Meaning that if the content of a cell matches the same cell on a second sheet then color it.

I would like to do this: if the text of a cell in the first row is present / matches the text in a row of the second sheet (so not the same cell), then color the whole row.

Link to sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ksJoxzVJJYiAkZzgK4pKz33I3DVjtFd-lD4-nnqIpI8/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after fiddeling around I got this to work

```
=$A1=vlookup(A1;indirect("Blad2!$A$1:$A$10");1;0)
```

This leaves me how to get the whole row colored. I have read somewhere I need to put a $ (now in front of A1), but this does not seem to work...

But after I changed the range it does!..Jippy to myself....